# What's the arch/arc/include directory for in linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I know the  `arch/arm/include`  represent arm arch. But I find `arch/arc/include`,
what's the **arc** directory for  ?

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6.7/source/arch

Comment: For arc architecture. What is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the directory for ARC architecture - DesignWare ARC processors from Synopsis.

Comment: The abbreviation arc  is similiar with arch  and I cannot search  information about arc, so I think it may be  a common module. Now I got it , thanks. @Aleksey